# Why are many Designer classes in System.Design marked as internal?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, design-time

I have been developing some components for our products at work, and one of them is based off the flow layout panel.

What i would like to do is provide a custom designer for it, but without loosing the features provided by it's default designer (`System.Windows.Forms.Design.FlowLayoutPanelDesigner`) which is marked as `internal`.

Using Reflector i thought i would just implement it again myself, seeing as it inherits from 'FlowPanelDesigner`and that from`PanelDesigner`  all of which are internal.

Why would these classes be specifically marked as internal? Is it due to them being specifically for Visual Studio use, and thus not 'framework' code?

Also, is there an easier option that re-implementing all the functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exposing code from a library has a high cost associayed with it. Exposing from a *framework* library even higher.

Ii **strongly** pushes you to maintain binary (and likely source) compatibility for the life of the product. Worse these are just the sort of things that vendors would be tempted to use which would mean that MS breaking any contracts on these classes would likely break a widget used my many hundreds or thousands of paying customers.

Breaking backward compatibility is something MSFT has historically avoided doing (witness the number of interfaces called Foo2, Foo3 and the methods call Blah and BlahEx). 
As they have steadily incurred considerable 'debt' in this manner over their life they have realised that avoiding these issues from the very beginning is the cheapest way to reduce such problems in the future. Thus any new public apis must justify their existence very strongly.

Design time code generation is the sort of area that strongly calls for improvements over the lifetime of a software eco-system (look at the partial class changes in VS for a major change in this area but there a many other smaller ones). By exposing classes which are heavily dependent on this infrastructure they would have limited their scope for changing the very infrastructure they view as their competitive advantage.

As such the sensible, safe approach is not to expose such classes. I certainly would have taken the same approach without being a company of Microsoft's size and customer base.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I'll guess Microsoft's answer would be either "That's just the way we made it", or "We wanted to reduce the burden of maintaining backwards compatibility."